# Add and show result of the sum of columns in a table

Tags: javascript

Good day.
I am a beginner in this, I have a table with the following records and I want to add the Red Team, Yellow Team and Turquoise Equipment column and show the sum in the labels that are at the top of the table

For this I attach my html code with jsp and the reference image
[Score Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUOQg.png)

```html
<div class="tabs-body">
                        <div class="tabs-item" id="tab1">
                               <div class="container"> 
                                    <div class="con-contador">
                 <label>Puntaje Rojo :</label>
                 <label id="projo" class="contador"></label>
                 <label >Puntaje Amarillo :</label>
                 <label id="pamarillo" class="contador"></label>
                 <label>Puntaje Turqueza :</label>
                 <label id="pturqueza" class="contador"></label>
                 
                 <a href="reportes.jsp" target="_blank" class="btnreporte">Reporte</a>
              
                  
             </div>
                                   <div class="table-responsive-vertical"  >
                <table id="reporte" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-mc-light-blue">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Disciplina</th>
                            <th>Categoria</th>
                            <th>Genero</th>
                            <th style="background-color: red">Equipo Rojo</th>
                            <th style="background-color: yellow">Equipo Amarillo</th>
                            <th style="background-color: turquoise">Puntaje Turqueza</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <%
                        for (int i=0; i < v.size();i++){
                            puntaje p = (puntaje)v.elementAt(i);
                        
                        %>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-title="Disciplina"><%=p.getNombredeporte()%></td>
                            <td data-title="Categoria"><%=p.getCategoria() %></td>
                            <td data-title="Genero"><%=p.getGenero() %></td>
                            <td data-title="Puntaje"><%=p.getPuntaje1() %></td>
                            <td data-title="Puntaje"><%=p.getPuntaje2() %></td>
                            <td data-title="Puntaje"><%=p.getPuntaje3() %></td>
                        </tr>
                       <%
                       }
                       %>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
                        </div>
                      
                    </div>
```

I understand that it can be done with a function in javascript but I am still a newbie, I ask for your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd say that JSP is Java Server Pages, not javascript. JSP code gets run (for example, generating puntaje sums) on the server before the webpage is returned to the web browser. In contrast, javascript code is executed after the webpage is returned to the web browser. Since you already have JSP code, why not just run your code server-side? Perhaps another "for" loop that runs to generate sums before your  elements. That said, if you really want to use javascript then the general procedure will be: add another data-attribute to your points TDs, like

```
<td data-puntaje-rojo=<%=p.getPuntaje1() %>>
```

Add classed spans to your labels like:

```
<label>Puntaje Rojo : <span class="puntaje-sum-rojo"></span></label>
```

Then in your javascript, use some form of selector to iterate over a collection/array of the TDs and store the sum of all data-puntaje-rojo values. Then, use javascript or jquery to inject the appropriate sum value into the appropriate label span.
While best practice is to store your javascript code in an external file on your web server website location, you can also write javascript directly inside of your JSP page, the javascript code must be inside  tags. And, it's best to have your javascript code run after your HTML is fully loaded: javascript and jquery both provide ways to accomplish that.